# Use GAS to Fetch URL, Then Take Screenshot (or Convert HTML to PDF/JPG)

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets, automation, scripting

### My Goal

I am, in short, attempting to create a script that visits a list of URLs and takes a screenshot of what is on the URL. For context, my goal is to save a snapshot that shows an image is listed on free stock photo sites (like pexels.com and unsplash.com).

### My Code So Far

Here is what I have so far:

```
function stockDatabasePDF(){
      var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
      var sheet = ss.getSheetByName('stock db');

      //make the pdf from the sheet
    var data = sheet.getRange('A2:A').getValues(); //these are your URLs to check
  
    for ( var i = 0; i < data.length; i++ ) {       
      if ( data[i][0] !== "" ) { //this means if your data (urls) are NOT blank
      
      var theurl = data[i][0];
        
      var token = ScriptApp.getOAuthToken();
      var docurl = UrlFetchApp.fetch(theurl, { headers: { 'Authorization': 'Bearer ' +  token } });
      var pdf = docurl.getBlob().setName('name').getAs('application/pdf');
      
        
      }
      //save the file to folder on Drive
    var fid = '1eHvWjIYyOeB9MQDwovzyXxx8CEIK5aOt';
    var folder = DriveApp.getFolderById(fid);
    var pdfs = folder.createFile(pdf).getUrl(); //both creates the file and copies the url
      }
 }
```

Just FYI... What is in range A2:A is the URLs to the stock photo sites, for example:

1. https://www.pexels.com/photo/person-riding-brown-horse-3490257/
2. https://unsplash.com/photos/Cz_SNZZyHgI

### The issue

This script seems to ALMOST work. But it runs into one of two problems:

1. I get a 403 response code (forbidden request)
2. The screenshot takes, but no images/css/etc. is included.
   [Here is an example of that](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0M12d.png)

### To Close

Any help here would be greatly appreciated. Please let me know if I left anything out or if anyone has any questions. Thank you all!

Comment: why would the file you grab return as a PDF? Check what file type is returned by the API of whatever service you are using. 403 errors usually occur because the server was not called properly. I would start with a service that has a documented REST API to test things out.

Comment: Unfortunately, at `UrlFetchApp.fetch()` and `getBlob()`, Javascript including in the site cannot be directly run. So when HTML is retrieved with `UrlFetchApp.fetch()`, the raw HTML is retrieved without running the Javascript. Although the raw HTML can be converted to PDF data, the Javascript is not run. How about this?

Comment: Hey medic, I was just trying to find a way to save it. Also to note, the 403 happened on one site (pexels.com) and not the other (unsplash.com).

Comment: Hey Tanaike, oh interesting. Yeah I did not know that. Any ideas on how to take a 'screenshot' via GAS without those functions?

Comment: Thank you for replying. I cannot understand about `without those functions`. Can I ask you about it? By the way, if you can use the low resolution image, how about using PageSpeed API? The sample script is https://gist.github.com/tanaikech/a434b4ed50d91fe5f56fffcf6bcb3f78

Comment: Hey Tanaike, sorry... I just basically meant is there another way to do it. I am fine with a low resolution image, so low as it is somewhat clear (things are legible, semi-clear, etc.). My only concern is that using the PageSpeed API... we would be cobbling two things together which might be more liable to break. Would you be able to combine that linked script with my code above (and propose as a solution). Not entirely sure how to combine mine and yours...

Comment: do you want to get photos from any site or a list of specific ones? because using ones with a public API (like unspalsh) is a lot easier see [their docs](https://unsplash.com/documentation). Also some sites (like unspalsh) require authentication before you can use them in a script.

Comment: hey medic, no I want to take a screenshot of the photo on the stock sites (unsplash, pexels, etc.)... as proof that that photo is listed on this site. sort of like a security policy. Use case... 1) a photographer uploads their photo to unsplash (with CC0 (perpetual free usage) license), 2) same photographer takes the photo, 3) photographer threatens to sue use for using a photo not being currently listed on unsplash.... in this instance, I can say, "no, here is a screenshot of the photo listed + a date stamp" (and yes, I know that there are sites like archive.org.. but I want this as a safety)

Comment: I don't think this can be done on sites that use authentication. They specifically fight scripts that access their servers. unsplash is a good example. even if technically possible it would be against the TOS

Comment: Ended up going with Tanaike's option. If you add this as the answer, I would be more than happy to accept it as the answer